# Dau Genton test - in grandmothers terms

Tags: monte-carlo, goodness-of-fit, spatial, nonparametric

**tl;dr**
Can you explain the Dau Genton test in terms a median grandmother could understand?

**Background:**
So I am looking for an "in.chull" for multivariate, concave hull, and I was going through "spatstat" and ran into something called Dau Genton test.  I was unfamiliar with it, and googled, but most of the descriptions are very technical and very spatial statistics focused.

Can you explain it in terms a median grandmother would understand?  What was the motivation?  How does it work?  When not to use it?  Does it have a "super-power"?

**References:**

- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.227.9890&rep=rep1&type=pdf  (original article 2011)
- https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/rssb.12172